# How to move MySQL Database to another server without downtime

Tags: linux, mysql, database-migration

We have quite big (1-4GB) MySQL Databases, which are used constantly for critical applications. We would like to move some of them to from physical server 1 (S1) to physical server 2 (S2).

The traditional way would be to stop MySQL in S1, make SQL Dump, import it to S2 and then start using S2 as production server. This works, but it will generate significant downtime to our customers, not least because we need to transfer several gigabytes of dump data over Internet.

Is it somehow possible to do this move with little or no downtime?

The one strategy that I have been thinking is something like that:

1. Start binlog in S1 for certain DB
2. Make SQL dump while S1 is still active in production. Dump would have some sort of timestamps corresponding to the binlogs
3. Transfer SQL dump to S2 and import it to new MySQL server
4. Let MySQL server on S2 replicate the difference (from binlogs) between the time when the dump started and now.
5. Set MySQL server on S2 to be slave for S1 and constantly replicate any changes on S1
6. Make DNS change so, that any new requests to S1 would be directed to S2 instead.

Would this work? And if it would, how could I do it? What should be taken into account?

Comment: can you change your code to read from S1 and S2 and write to S2 only?

Comment: Not very easily. Our application needs to read and write from the same database. Also because we use several client applications that connect to the sql directly, its pretty impossible to update them all at once. That way we would have some of them writing to S1 and some to S2 which would be a mess.

Comment: It's quite easy to move a mysql db without downtime, check this out: https://ao.gl/moving-a-mysql-database-without-downtime/

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience in doing what you just asked, but I'm learning the subject now, since I'm trying to find out, how I would be able to do it in the future, when the time will come, and if there are things I can do now in order to make it possible later.

While looking for a solution I found the [following post](http://plusbryan.com/mysql-replication-without-downtime), that more or less describe what you just asked. besides the last part of changing the DNS and start working on the slave DB. I haven't tried it myself, but at the post he also describe the procedure on how to exactly do that.

It looks to me that it can be done, and I hope that you will succeed. You might be able to ask the guy who wrote the post on the last step as well.

[This](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-solutions-switch.html) worth checking as well, I think that it closing the whole loop

Good luck